# self error when launching a local command with fabric2

Tags: python, fabric

Here is my code :

```
from fabric2 import Connection
cbis = Connection.local()
with cbis.cd('/home/bussiere/Workspace/Stack/Event/'):
    cbis.run('git add .')
```

but i have this error :

```
TypeError: local() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

how to launch a command on local with fabric2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you should instantiate the `Connection` class somehow, like this:

```
cbis = Connection(possibly some arguments).local()
```

This error happens because classes are objects in Python. You could write your own example that would produce the same error:

```
class Test:
    def function(self):
        print('hey')

Test.function()
Test().function()
```

Here the first call does not instantiate a `Test` object, and thus, no implicit first argument is supplied to `function`. This results in an error. The second call calls the function *of an instance* of `Test` and does pass the implicit first argument (that is, that same instance) to `function`. This function expects exactly one argument, so everything works fine.